# Why "Begin Upgrade" not appearing on Dashboard of Firebase Console?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics

I can't find "Begin Upgrade" at Firebase > Dashboard as described at https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/10960488

Is it because I already upgraded (I can't remember that...), or my project can't be upgraded due to eligibility issues?

UPDATE:
I followed the steps provided by Matias N Goldberg (thank you!), and it appears that Google Analytics is upgraded for my two projects.
However, even though both projects are upgraded, one project shows old UI while the other shows the new UI (e.g. "Add Filter" vs. "Add Comparison")

Why is that?

Screenshots followed:

Project 1:
[image]

Project 2:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Go to Project Overview -> Project Settings -> Integration -> Google Analytics -> Manage

If you haven't upgraded yet the following should appear:

[image]

If it doesn't appear, then you already upgraded or there is a bug (this feature just rolled out so expect possible trouble)

After a successful upgrade, you should see "Linked Google Analytics account" like in this picture:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Project seems to be upgraded, however, Firebase dashboard still seems to show the old UI rather than new UI. See UPDATE on my original post.